# have method implement from interface yet override generic type

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have an interface as below:

```
public interface Functor<T> {
    public <R> Functor<R> chain(Function<T, Functor<R>> f);
}
```

and I want to implement such that:

```
public abstract class Either<T> implements Functor<T> {
    private static class Right<T> extends Either<T> {
        private T val;

        private Right(final T val) {
            this.val = val;
        }

        public <R> Either<R> chain (final Function<T, Either<R>> f) {
            return f.apply(this.val);
        }
    }
}
```

The reason being that I want to be able to "chain" over any `Functor<T>` yet I want those functors to require that the same type as it is returned by chain.

The only way I was able to get this to work was:

```
public interface Functor<T> {
    public <R> Functor<R> chain(Function<T, ? extends Functor<R>> f);
}

public abstract class Either<T> implements Functor<T> {
    public static class Right<T> extends Either<T> {
        private T val;

        private Right(final T val) {
            this.val = val;
        }

        public <R> Either<R> chain(final Function<T, ? extends Functor<R>> f) {
            return (Either<R>)f.apply(this.val);
        }
    }
}
```

However this doesn't express exactly what I want... the type conversion to `(Either<R>)` isn't the best way to solve this for sure.

Any attempt as putting `? extends Either<R>` or just `Either<R>` fails with "Right is not abstract and does not override abstract method <R>chain..."

Anyone have any idea of what I can do to solve this?
IS there a way to do this?

Comment: You know that's a monad, not a functor, right?  But generally speaking, there's no way to express what you're trying to express in Java's type system.  The real issue is that Java can't express higher-kinded type variables.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi, yes, that's true.  It's not clear why that's relevant?

Comment: Yep I know that.. but at the moment I've just stuck map, chain etc in the same interface...

Comment: @LuisWasserman so it looks like I'll be waiting for Java 10's reified generics? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Valhalla_(Java_language)

Comment: I wouldn't expect even that to let you express what you're trying to express.  Reification doesn't address the root issue of referring to higher-kinded type variables.

Comment: Well, if the interface mandates that you can pass a `Function<T, Functor<R>>` to the method, you can’t restrict it in an implementation class to accept a `Function<T, Either<R>>` only. This has nothing to do with Generics nor type erasure, it’s the simplest principle of Java’s (and most other) OOP system. You can’t restrict a method to accept less than the method of a super type. But you can introduce another type parameter for the result type of the `Function`…